# List of definitions: how to remove the prefix "Definition"?

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, thmtools

I have write definitions in this way (this is a MWE class unatesi is available [here](http://www.fisica.unina.it/didattica/area_studenti/unatesi.zip)):

```
\documentclass[laurea,oneside,12pt,italian]{unatesi}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}

\begin{document}
    \begin{defin}[Definition's name]
        Lorem ipsum dolorem
    \end{defin}

    \listoftheorems
\end{document}
```

So when list is printed, it shows something like that:

> 1  Definition (Definition's name)............................ 1

But I want something like

> 1  Definition's name............................................. 1

There's a way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that reveals your document class plus the packages relevant for typesetting the theorems.

Comment: MWE is present now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to redefine the macro responsible for writing the relevant data in the `loe` file:

```
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}
\makeatletter
\def\ll@defin{%
  \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
  \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg
    \thmt@thmname
  \else
    \thmt@shortoptarg
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Of course it's better to use the interface of `thmtools` for defining new theorem-like environments, in order to decide which ones go to the list of theorems, for instance.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Yes, egreg can even beat the respective package author. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Oh, sorry. :)